# How to create group chats and send messages to MS Teams from my backend application

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, chatbot

What I am trying to do is notify users in MS Teams when certain events trigger in my application.

Required functionality:

- Message a user directly when event has been triggered on my application
- Create a group chat with multiple users and message them all if an event is triggered that affects them all

I can do this in Slack, by creating a slack bot and using:

```js
// single message
const web = new WebClient(token);
web.chat.postMessage({
  text: message,
  channel: target,
});

// group message
const conversationResponse = await web.conversations.open({
  users: targets.join(","),
});
web.chat.postMessage({
  text: message,
  channel: conversationResponse.channel.id,
});
```

I tried to do this with a chatbot in MS Teams, but came across [this limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1303725/whether-teams-bot-can-actively-create-group-chat)

> Creating group chats through Bot APIs is not supported. However, this can be accomplished with Graph APIs

So I tried the Graph API next.

This is a backend application and I don't need/want users to have to do the OAuth handshake just to get notifications in Teams.

Ideally if I have the user's email or their id in MS Teams, I would like to be able to notify them without complicated auth token handshakes for each user to have to manage themselves.

So I opted for application-only authentication.

I got it all set up, but then was blocked by this limitation when I tried to post a message:

> Message POST is allowed in application-only context only for import purposes. Refer to https://docs.microsoft.com/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/import-messages/import-external-messages-to-teams for more details.

Do I need to use a weird hybrid approach, where I create the group chat via the Graph API and then use the chat bot to message them?

Can anyone help shed light on how I can achieve my goals?

Comment: So, in your case, a hybrid approach might be necessary where you create the group chat via the Graph API and then use the chat bot to message them. But, this approach might not be ideal as it involves complicated auth token handshakes for each user to manage themselves.

Comment: Another approach could be using Incoming Webhooks to post messages from your application to Teams. Incoming Webhooks are simple to use and do not require any installation steps in Teams or Azure resources. However, they do not support messaging individual person or group chat.
For more information, you can refer to the - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/notification-bot-in-teams?tabs=ts1%2Cts2%2Cts3%2Cts4%2Cjsts%2Cts5#notification-bot-in-teams

Comment: Thanks. I will look into the option to use both and also the option to just push the messages to a shared channel and just tag the users that need to know about the notification. I think that will give them the notification and they can discuss in a thread underneath that post if they need. That might be a good compromise.